# Laravel not loading CSS properly

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

I'm having issues when trying to load some properties of my main.css file, loading the file from /user_create.html loads the main.css just fine, but when I try to do it from url.dev/user/create, it doesn't load all the properties, and the code is copy/pasted from html to my blade.php file.

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid band-user-creation">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="row">
               <div class="col-lg-4"></div>
               <div class="col-lg-4 raleway-regular"><table >
              <tbody>                   
                ...
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="UserName" type="name" class="input-user-creation" placeholder="Ingresa tu Nombre"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><input name="UserLastName" type="lastname" class="input-user-creation" placeholder="Ingresa tu Apellido"></td>
                </tr>
                ...
```

CSS

```
.band-user-creation{
padding-top: 100px;
padding-bottom: 100px;
color: #212121;
text-align: center;
}

.input-user-creation{
background-color: #B2DD4C;
font-size: x-large;
border-radius: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
border: transparent;
color: #F9F9F9;
margin-top: 5px;
min-width: 300px;
}
```

[image]

.HTML HEAD CONTENT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>...</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400i,600,600i" rel="stylesheet">

...

...

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js">
</script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**EDIT**

.BLADE HEAD CONTENT

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>...</title>
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../../main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400i,600,600i" rel="stylesheet">  

...

...

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Did you see the .css file when you inspect the code? if you see, whats happens when you access to that file on the browser?

Comment: Can you post the `<head>` content of your html in both the `user_create.html` file and the `.blade.php` file?

Comment: @AgeValed I'm not seing .band-user-creation class nor .input-user-creation class :/

Comment: Are there any 404 errors in the inspector console ?

Comment: @Schavcovsky where did you add that css styles? you need to add a css file with all the styles on the layout blade

Comment: @stratedge done, look at the edit

Comment: @AlexvanVliet there's no 404 errors on the console.

Comment: @AgeValed you can see that now at the edit.

Comment: Any improvement with changing the stylesheet locations in the blade file to `/css/bootstrap.css` and `/main.css` (basically, get rid of the `../..` in each)?

Comment: @Schavcovsky check my answer, that could help to improve the code maybe that will fix the issue

Comment: @stratedge moving ../main.css to ../css/main.css did the trick

Answer (score 1):

you need a layout blade blank.blade.php (folder resources\views\layouts) with

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="{{ asset("css/style.css") }}" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body 
        @yield('main_container')
    </body>
</html>
```

then you need your style .css with all the css on inside public folder
then on your .blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.blank')
@section('main_container')
    <!-- ALL THE HTML -->
@endsection
```

Comment: Thank you @AgeValed moving the main.css did the trick, I'm not quite sure why "kinda" work before, when it shouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

Moving ../main.css to ../css/main.css did the trick, I don't why still kinda work before when It shouldn't...

Comment: Is your `main.css` file in the `css` folder in your `public` folder?

Comment: @stratedge main.css is now in the css folder, it was in the root folder before

Comment: Your problem looks to me like you were incorrectly **relatively** referencing the locations for your CSS files. I'll write up an answer to explain.

Comment: On second thought, maybe not - I'd need to see the full URL paths used and the directory structure, and if you have it all working, it's likely not worth the effort

Comment: Thank you a lot @stratedge as you said everything is working and that's what matter the most ! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

the main idea about loading CSS/js use asset() helper

for example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/fontawesome- 
    free/css/all.min.css') }}">
```